# automating tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, automation, tortoisesvn

I want to automate the checkout of a working copy of an existing repository to a desired location. I am using Tortoise SVN on windows 7 and i will not be able to use any other forms of SVN as http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html suggests, as i have not admin rights and the whole department is using Tortoise SVN. I know i can use commands to open the GUI's but is it possible to interact with these GUI's or even better create a command that doesn't necessarily require the GUI's

TortoiseProc.exe/command:checkout /url:[source]  /path:[destination] - opens the chekout GUI, how can i "press" OK from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to interact with these GUI's or even better create a command that doesn't necessarily require the GUI's

From "Automating TortoiseSVN" page

> Remember that TortoiseSVN is a GUI client, and this automation guide
>   shows you how to make the TortoiseSVN dialogs appear to collect user
>   input. **If you want to write a script which requires no input, you
>   should use the official Subversion command line client instead**.

So answer is: "Use SVN CLI, which is part of TortoiseSVN installation in TSVN 1.7" and checkout using

`svn co URL PATH`

Answer (score 0):

Here you can download the Subversion Command line tools for Windows:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/

Choose a zip package, so you should be able to install/extract it without admin rights.

`svn checkout` is [documented here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) or via `svn help checkout` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I think one needs to know these commands that will help automating anything related to svn. I used svn extensively while creating automation frameworks .

Visit this link to get the full idea

http://thebongtraveller.blogspot.com/2016/01/svn-commands-you-must-know-test.html